# Set the static IP address of an Azure VM

Tags: azure, ip, virtual-machine

Trying to create an AD DC in an Azure VM. According to my [guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22622.building-your-first-domain-controller-on-2012-r2.aspx) I need to set a static IP address before I install AD DC on the server. I tried doing it but just lead to me losing the connection to the server and having to create a new one.

ipconfig:
[image]

Setting static IPv4:[image]

What should I input for the static values in IPv4 above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not alter these values from inside the vm, it might render the vm without networking :) You should alter the NIC ip address configuration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-reserved-private-ip
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-static-private-ip-arm-pportal

Comment: Thanks, one question on this. When I later want to connect a VM to this domain, how do I do this with an Azure VM? Usually you go to the same window I have in my question and configure it there.

Comment: if you want to connect vm ot a domain youve setup in azure you do the same thing you usually do, but you should configure networking on the Azure side, not inside the VM. You can use the portal experience to make your VM to use your another Azure VM (that is a DC) as a dns server

Comment: Okay, so I should not do like this: www.itexperience.net/2014/06/06/an-active-directory-domain-controller-ad-dc-for-the-domain-x-x-com-could-not-be-contacted-windows-azure/ ? Do you have a link? Confusing cus if I ping my DC IP Adress it finds it, but it does not find the DNS for it, so cant add to workgroup

Comment: well, you could edit dns manually (technically nothing should break, but it can). just go to network interface properties (in Azure Portal) and select "DNS Serves" there. And edit configuration there.